# How do you default to walking directions when you open a google maps URL?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

Currently I am doing this to 'get directions':

```
NSString *googleMapsURLString;
googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",
                           curLoc.latitude,     // Start
                           curLoc.longitude,
                           self.hotspot.coordinate.latitude,
                           self.hotspot.coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"Opening URL: %@",googleMapsURLString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Does anyone know if there is a parameter to get directions via walking instead of defaulting to driving?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add

```
dirflg=w
```

to your parameters.

Comment: It donsn't appear to work.  `Opening URL: http://maps.google.com/?mode=walking&saddr=51.504303,-0.114187&daddr=51.502859,-0.107943` and it still give driving directions...

Comment: Ah, good point, that parameter is only for the json request. I'll change my answer now.

Comment: What other values can be set to dirflag in case we want directions for transit dirctions or bicycle directions? Is there a way to get approximate time required to travel the route by each mode of transportation?

Comment: @amol_subhedar Use **r** for *transit*, **b** for *bicycle*, **d** for *driving*, **h** for *avoid highways*, **t** for *avoid tolls*.

Comment: @amol_subhedar As for travel time, the request returns a *duration* element that provide the estimated time.